# Live reload is not possible without a body or a head tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio, liveserver

My program is to store the number of entries through the entry button and save it through the save button...

So,  I added a JS link in my HTML body tag and then ran it through the live server or tried to store it, it shows "live reload is not possible without body or head tag"...

Comment: Perhaps you're misreadng the error message ... there are NO google results for `"live to reload is not possible without body or head tag"` - there are hundreds for `"live reload is not possible without body or head tag"` - many of which will provide a solution for you

Answer (score 0):

Then add a body and head tag!

```html
<head>
  <!-- head stuff -->
  <script src="whatever"></script>
  <meta something>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Main body stuff -->
  <div id="mydiv"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue as I was working through the I am Tim Corey Web Development course using the Edge browser. I had the necessary head and body tags, but I was getting that error whenever I launched live server. The solution that worked for me was simply closing the server port, saving my project again, and relaunch the live server. If you're still having issues, double check that you've spelled the tags correctly.